# Airflow: connection type for SQL Server missing

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server through Airflow.

I have gone to Admin -> Connections and I am trying to add a new connection, however the connection type for Microsoft SQL Server is missing. I only see MySql.

I have downloaded the provider package and I am able to use the `MsSqlOperator` in my code:

```
package: pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql
```

Comment: which airflow version are you using ?

Comment: my version is 2.3.2

Comment: I am now getting a import error in the UI: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql'. However I have installed the provider package

Comment: are you able to create connection manually ? "airflow connections --conn-type mssql connection_name" ? did you install successfully pymssql ?